# Error in fitsiolib for MATLAB: couldn't create the named file

Tags: matlab, image-processing, fits

I need to write a set of images, which are calculated in a for loop. If I define the path using `sprintf`, I get the error

```
Error using fitsiolib
CFITSIO library error (105): couldn't create the named file

Error in matlab.io.fits.createFile (line 32)
fptr = fitsiolib('create_file',filename);

Error in fitswrite (line 67)
fptr = fits.createFile(filename);

Error in Calculation_correction_image (line 23)
fitswrite(image_calculated, t);
```

Do you have any suggestion on how to avoid this? Here is the code section where the images are calculated:

```
k = 0;
for j=0:40
    image_calculated = (image_summed_start - (image_correction*j))/image_summed_start;
    t = sprintf('image_projection_%02i.fits',j)
    A = j
    fitswrite(image_calculated, t);
end
```

Comment: It may be writing to a path in your computer where it requires permission.  Try moving your code / working directory to somewhere else where you know you have permission to write.

Comment: I am quite sure the filename generated by `sprintf` is inculpable. Beside permission issues I could imagine a full hard disk or other hardware problems... did you try with smaller images?

Comment: I observed similar behaviour though I could run the above code successfully.  If I repeatedly ran  `fitswrite(img,'destfile.fits')`, it worked every time, creating the file and replacing it - with or without the full path.  If I tried `fitswrite(img,'destfile')` - no extension - the error was generated (if the file existed or not).  If I added the path - no extension - it worked the first time only.  Put any extension (.fi,.geo,.sthg) and any combination of fitswrite would work.  The code would fail anytime that fitswrite.m (or fits.createFile.m) had to add an extension.